# Can you do google ad conversion tracking in Universal Analytics?

Tags: events, google-analytics, adsense, universal-analytics

I set up conversion tracking on the Google ads dashboard and it gave me snippets to use on my app. The snippets are all for GA4.

On the app I need to support both GA4 and Universal Analytics. I fire events to both properties. But I can't find anywhere online examples of how fire ad conversion tracking events in UA, it's all in GA4.

Is there a UA equivalent of this GA4 code?:

```
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'Some/Id',
      'transaction_id': '',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
```

Or can google ad conversions only be tracked in GA4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G-Tag can be used for both Google ADs as well as Analytics reporting

ASwell as with ANalytics you first need to initialize G-Tag and configure it:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: CONVERSION_ID -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-CONVERSION_ID"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config','AW-CONVERSION_ID');
  </script>
```

Then send the Conversion Data.

```
    <script>
      gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-CONVERSION_ID/CONVERSION_LABEL',
        'value': 1.0,
        'currency': 'USD'
      });
    </script>
```

The Conversion ID and LAbel can be retrieved from the Google Ads Interface when selecting manual Implementation.